# XCodeの補完機能の使い方

Tags: xcode

XCodeの補完機能の使い方で質問があります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

のように補完機能で「AVPlayerItem?」を入力し終えます。
その後、
1. 「▶︎」ボタンで")"の右側にカーソルを移動させる
2. マウスポインタで")"の右側にカーソルを移動させる
の方法で入力は終了しますが、なんとなくスマートではないかと感じています。
特にプレースホルダーの後に文字列があるような場合に、特にスマートでは無いと感じています。

もっといい方法で補完機能を使えるような方法をご存知の方は、ご教授いただきたくよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

placeholderがハイライトしている状態でリターンキーを叩くとそのままでいいアイテムの場合にはプレースホルダーだった文字列が、平文になります。
クロージャーの展開なんかはこれで充分ですよね。

自分が意図した文字列（変数名）の場合はプレースホルダーがハイライトしている状態でその文字列の先頭文字を打ち始めれば、プレースホルダー文字列だったところに打ち始めた文字で始まる変数／メソッドへの補完が始まります。

移動は、`option`+(`◀`|`▶︎`)　又は`option`+`ctrl`+(`b`|`f`)で、単語境界毎に移動するので、カーソル左右移動キーを押す際に`option`キーを押しながらにすれば大抵は事足りるのではないでしょうか？
同様に行末、行頭に移動するのであれば、`command`+(`◀`|`▶︎`)で移動可能です。

Xcode 10からは、`option`+`click`だけでなくキー操作でもマルチカーソルが使えるようになったらしいですが、まだ試していません